# How to hide ng-table columns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I I've tried using ng-hide and ng-show to show one different column when `vm.allRecords` is set to true:

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" ng-hide="vm.noRecords || vm.DashboardService.loading">
    <tr ng-repeat="record in $data">
        <td title="'Title'" sortable="'title'" class="title">
            <a ng-href="{{vm.baseUrl}}#entity/displayEntity?entityId={{record.entityId}}" target="_blank">
                {{record.title}}
            </a>
        </td>
        <td title="'Date Created'" sortable="'createdDate'" class="date">{{record.createdDate}}</td>
        <td title="'Last Modified'" sortable="'lastModified'" class="date">{{record.lastModified}}</td>
        <td title="'Notebook Descriptor'" sortable="'notebookDescription[0]'" class="description">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="description in record.notebookDescription">{{description}}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td title="'Witness'" sortable="'witnesses[0].display'" class="witness" ng-hide="vm.allRecords"> 
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="witness in record.witnesses">{{witness.display}}</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td title="'Due Date'" sortable="'dueDate'" class="date" ng-hide="vm.allRecords">{{record.dueDate}}</td>
        <td title="'Status'" sortable="'status'" class="status" ng-show="vm.allRecords">{{record.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but the cells in the header are not hidden. I've also try to use custom th using this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Date Created</th>
    <th>Last Modified</th>
    <th>Notebook Descriptor</th>
    <th ng-hide="vm.allRecords">Witness</th>
    <th ng-hide="vm.allRecords">Due Date</th>
    <th ng-show="vm.allRecords">Status</th>
</tr>
```

it work but I don't have sorting. How can I hide columns and have sorting?

Comment: Put a jsfiddle together. I think you are doing the opposite, that's why it wont work

Comment: @yBrodsky here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/39wcrt02/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've changed ng-show/ng-hide to ng-if and it work.

Comment: To complete the answer, the option that meets the most expectations of the question would be the ng-if, since it specifically hides the column, while the ng-hide or ng-show does not hide the <head...